Transitioning Standalone Ubuntu Desktops to Centralized Management in a College Lab: Best Practices and Pitfalls
Our college lab consists of 10 Ubuntu desktops, each currently set up as standalone machines on the LAN. I want to transition them to a centrally managed environment while avoiding common pitfalls. I have minimal experience with Ansible and am open to using it or other tools for configuration management.
Key Requirements:

Resume Work on Any Machine:  Students need to log in to any desktop and access their files and settings seamlessly. What's the best solution—networked home directories, DFS, or centralized authentication (e.g., LDAP, Active Directory)? What challenges should I be aware of when implementing these solutions?

Avoid Single Points of Failure:  I want to distribute services (authentication, file storage, updates) across multiple machines to ensure resilience. How can I achieve this, and what should I consider to avoid downtime or data loss?

Existing Infrastructure:

Office 365 subscription: Can this be leveraged for authentication or file sharing in a Linux environment?
FortiClient SSL VPN: How can this be integrated for secure remote access while maintaining simplicity and avoiding potential security issues?


Centralized Management:

Considering my minimal experience with Ansible, would it be a suitable tool for managing software updates, installations, and user permissions across all systems?
Are there other tools I should consider?
What are common pitfalls when using Ansible (or similar tools) in this context?



Current Setup:

OS: Ubuntu on each desktop (standalone)
Primary Use: Programming, browsing.

I'm looking for practical, cost-effective solutions to ensure a smooth and resilient transition. Any advice on best practices, tools, and potential pitfalls would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance for your guidance!

Your question is too broad to easily answer in our Q&A format. There is no one-size fits all solution, unfortunately.  We're much better in answering specific questions, when you have already done your own research, made your own attempts and run into problems. Microsoft for example provides documentation for leveraging and integrating  your existing Microsoft (Azure) based infrastructure with Linux  for authentication and to access file shares https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-identity-auth-linux-kerberos-enable

My personal preference is to leverage as much of your existing IT infrastructure as possible, as then I need to maintain as few components of my. So indeed authenticate to your Microsoft domain so your users have a single account everywhere. Using Kerberos is well supported on Linux clients, and over equally well supported LDAP, that has the benefit that you get single-sign on, which  then allows you for example to use a successful log on for Kerberos authentication to file shares and with automount, give automatic access to centrally stored files on the file share that belong to your user.
